# how to build a template based on the user record

Tags: workflow, email-template, merge-field

I am trying to create a template that reports on the user record details. However I run into an issue when I create an email alert form a workflow that is triggered when a new user record is created. I want to pass the user details through to the template, however the template display the user details of the running user of the workflow. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you share the template you have been trying to use?

Comment: no need, I found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reference the target user record, I should use {!Target_User.[FIELD]} where [FIELD] is the field name.
[Link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=merge_fields_email_templates.htm&language=en_US)

[image: Workflow reference to target user]

Answer (score 1):

It is worth to consider setting up a trigger on your object and send an email from within it. This way you can parse the template on your own in Apex, like:

```
string subject = template.Subject;
string body = template.HtmlValue;

subject = subject.replace('{my_tag}', 'my value');
body = body.replace('{another_tag}', 'some value');
```

Comment: slightly too complex a solution for what we need. I always try to build in Salesforce through point and click rather than code but thanks for your answer.